# Can a wizard with cleric levels scribe wizard spells he had prepared from the cleric class in his spellbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, cleric

There's been a debate on a D&D discord server that's caused me a lot of trouble. Here is the question: if a wizard 2/cleric 2 has a wizard spell prepared from being a cleric, rather than from being a wizard, then should the wizard-cleric not be able to then scribe that spell into their spellbook the same as if they had it prepared from anywhere else?

**Edit:** This is different to the bard/wizard question due to bards having spells known, and clerics preparing spells just as wizards do.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I mean I was going to propose [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103231/can-i-copy-prepared-cleric-spells-that-are-also-on-the-wizard-spell-list-into-my?noredirect=1&lq=1) but it's closed as a dupe of the one I linked before

Comment: Please note that the three answers at the dupe take a slightly different approach, and that the difference in votes isn't all that much; you are not bound to accept the accepted answer, but it may be, to you, the one that makes the most sense.