# Could an Artificer / Wizard multiclass add any of their prepared spells to their own spellbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, artificer

Or would they have to go through the process, and cost, of scribing a scroll of, say Detect Magic, then pass an Arcana check to 'learn' and spend more precious gp to scribe it into their spellbook?

If the Artificer multiclassed into Wizard, could they then prepare said spells and directly Scribe them? Thereby skipping the scroll creation to learning process.

Comment: And how are they preparing a spell they don't know?

Comment: @NautArch: Assuming D&D 5E, Artificers prepare spells daily from the entire Artificer list (they have no equivalent to a spellbook). In a party with an Artificer and a Wizard, at the cost of scribing scrolls, the Wizard can learn every spell overlapping the Artificer list as soon as the Artificer reaches the level to cast it.

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Answer (score -1):

### You can only write Wizard spells to your spellbook

How spellbooks work is explained on p. 114 PHB:

> **Copying a Spell into the Book**. When you find a **wizard spell**
> of 1st level or higher, you can add it to your spellbook if it is
> of a level for which you have spell slots and if you can spare
> the time to decipher and copy it. (...)
> You can only copy wizard spells into the book, no matter if the spell is prepared, from a scroll, or from another spell book of yours. Not all Artificer spells are also Wizard spells, so you would not be able to copy *cure wounds* or *aid*.

In addition, the Spellcasting section under Multiclassing (PHB p. 164) says:

> Spells Known and Prepared. **You determine
> what spells you know and can prepare for each class
> individually**, as if you were a single-classed member of
> that class.

So even if you have access to a spell that it also on the Wizard list via your Artificer levels, it is not a Wizard spell for you, it is an Artificer spell, and you cannot copy it into your book. Again, this is independent of if you have prepared the spell or not.

The rules for copying prepared spells are a bit indirect (also on P 114, PHB):

> **Replacing the Book**. You can copy a spell from your own spellbook into another book—for example, if you want to make a backup copy of your spellbook. This is just like copying a new spell into your spellbook, but faster and easier, since you understand your own notation and already know how to cast the spell. You need spend only 1 hour and 10 gp for each level of the copied spell. 
> If you lose your spellbook, you can use the same procedure to transcribe the spells that you have prepared into a new spellbook. Filling out the remainder of your spellbook requires you to find new spells to do so, as normal. For this reason, many wizards keep backup spellbooks in a safe place.

It's generally understood that there is nothing stopping you from making such a copy from your prepared spells, even if you have not yet lost your old spellbook.

Comment: The purpose of the gold badge is to be able to close duplicates without requiring five votes, not so that you can unilaterally reopen obvious duplicates so you can get another answer in.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov, I did not. I responded to a reopen queue request.

Comment: Well it can be hard to tell the difference when you reopened a question that was closed as a duplicate by a moderator and then wrote [essentially the same answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/103235/62294) as the one to the linked question. Is there something about this question that makes it substantially different from the linked duplicate so that it ought be treated separately?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Apologies, I thought it was closed before because it was missing the game edition tag, not as a dupe. So when I saw the reopen request, I checked, saw the tag was added, and voted to reopen, then posted the answer. I think you or Someone_evil closed it as a duplicate after that, but I may just have missed some of the convolutions here.

Comment: 1. Closed as needing clarity 2. Edited to add tag and details. 3. Someone_Evil re-closed it as duplicate to swap the close reason. 4. Reopened. 5. Answered. 6. Re-closed. [Timeline](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/204276/timeline)

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin Please try to take a little more time when reviewing questions for closure and reopening. At the very least, check the comments to see if other users have left comments relevant to the review task. In this case, [Someone_Evil's comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/204276/could-an-artificer-wizard-multiclass-add-any-of-their-prepared-spells-to-their#comment559483_204276) explaining the duplicate closure was available to you at the time you performed the review. There will almost always be a comment(s) giving context to closure and reopening review tasks.

Comment: To jump in to point out a relevant quirk which may explain things, the reopen queue item Groody acted on was not closed by me reopening the question. Had I not reclosed it it would probably have been invalidated. Caching is more to blame than anyone else, and the closest thing to harm is that Groody wasted some effort in an answer. Let it be.

Comment: Relevant: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/