# Can Innate Spellcasters cast spells from scrolls?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

Kinda a follow-up from [What creatures can cast spells from scrolls?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122229/what-creatures-can-cast-spells-from-scrolls). Actually, a more specific case, just to be sure.

About Spell Scrolls:

> If the spell is on your class’s spell list, you can read the scroll and cast its spell without providing any material Components. Otherwise, the scroll is unintelligible.

From what I understand from the rulings and seems to be accepted by [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/122234/43856), creatures can only cast spells from spell scrolls if they have a Spellcasting ability linked to a class. Innate Spellcasters don't, so they can't. Is that right?

In particular, does it change if the Spell Scroll is specific to a Spell that the Creature knows? For example, can a Mind Flayer (the normal one, not the Arcanist Variant) cast Dominate Monster from a spell scroll? (*Mind Flayers* can otherwise innately cast the spell)

I can see it being house-ruled as a Yes, similar to [how clerics can cast Fireballs from scrolls](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/57742/43856) (depending on their domain), since the spells they learn from the domain are included on their "class' spell list", but from RAW I understand it as a No. Is my reading correct?

Comment: The reason I don't see it as a duplicate from the first is because from my point of view the particularity of this case is not completely encompassed by the previous question (reason why I got in doubt, to begin with). I can see the previous question being edited to include this one, but I didn't want to edit someone's else question.

Comment: [Yannick MG](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/42215/yannick-mg) and I talked a little about this question on the chat. Link to the start of the conversation [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44514869#44514869). It might help to understand the question better. I'm not sure if any of it should be added to the question itself though.

Comment: Its a duplicate - the accepted answer to that question is the answer to this question.

Comment: I believe I have now thoroughly answered this question after expanding on [my other answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122229/what-creatures-can-cast-spells-from-scrolls/122234#122234).